# Remove first character from a string if it is a comma

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to setup a function in javascript to remove the first character of a string but only if it is a comma `,`.  I've found the `substr` function but this will remove anything regardless of what it is.

My current code is

```
text.value = newvalue.substr(1);
```

Comment: Direct sting manipulation will generally be faster than a regex. I would go with Max S' first answer.

Comment: @Jan Aagaard And so would I probably if this is an operation to be performed several times. I do, however, find the regex easier to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
text.value = newvalue.replace(/^,/, '');
```

Edit: Tested and true. This is just *one* way to do it, though.

Comment: what is to test? replace open anchor comma with empty. you got it.

Comment: @Sky Yup, but I like to run through jsbin.com to verify ... and eliminate typos etc. (It's still morning here in Denmark.)

Comment: Most of the time performance difference between these methods wont matter, but keep in mind that `.replace` is super slow compared to `.substr` or `.slice`. See this benchmark for details: http://jsperf.com/replace-first-charachter-of-string-if-it-is-x

Comment: I don't have a solution unless doing a DO WHILE... but what if the string starts with 2 comas or 3... you'll have the same initial problem.  It should remove the comas until the string is not starting with a coma anymore. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 16):

```
s = (s.length && s[0] == ',') ? s.slice(1) : s;
```

Or with a regex:

```
s = s.replace(/^,/, '');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = (myString[0] == ',') ? myString.substr(1) : myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the tips, got a working code here for myself.
it will copy every list item and remove the 1st coma.

```
var list_with_coma = ", " + list_item;
var unwantedCharacter = ",";

$('#id_of_input').val(function(){
if (this.value.charAt(0) == unwantedCharacter){
this.value = this.value.substr(1);}
return this.value + list_with_coma;
});
```