# Remove first character from a string if it is 0

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I know it is related to [Remove first character from a string if it is a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182596/remove-first-character-from-a-string-if-it-is-a-comma) but in this case that solution doesn't work for me. Maybe its because now I'm dealing with a number. Simply I want javascript to remove `0` from `08` but don't touch `10`; only remove `0` when it is the first character.

This solution doesn't work: `replace(/^0/, "")`

Comment: Beucase, apparently he is trying to call it on a Number i think.

Comment: use `parseInt()`. Integers dont have a leading zero.

Comment: `parseInt("08", 10);`

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't work"? Are you calling `.replace()` on a string that starts with `"08"`? If so, how is the result incorrect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

```
alert("08".replace(/^0+/, ''));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xyaf8w8p/)**

And if you are dealing with numbers then you can use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Javascript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

Comment: `/^0+/` removes not only the first zero character, but all the zeros that are in the beginning of a string. Depending of what you need it may be correct or it may not.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way with regex :

> ^0+(?!$)

and feel free to use `String replaceFirst` function.