# How to remove the 1st character if a comma from a cell value using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm iterating over a range and the rows whose conditions are met, gets one of its column's cell value pushed into an array. Now, from the second iteration on, there shouldn't be a `,` at the beginning, but this is naturally inherited.

```
for (var a = 0; a < dataRng.length; a++) {
    if (dataRng[a][1] == true && dataRng[a][0] == 'SHIPPED' && dataRng[a][40] != 'Yes') {
      msgBody.push(dataRng[a][37].toString().replace(',', '') + '\n');
      
      var iteratedRow = a + 3
      sheet.getRange(iteratedRow, 41).setValue('Yes')      
    }
   }
```

This is the result now:
[image]

So, right at the beginning of the second row, that comma shouldn't be there and it should begin with 'NPA...'

Thank you!

Comment: About `This is the result now:`, where is the second row? Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the values or the image?

Comment: Just added it, @Tanaike! Sorry I didn't notice it loses the format, bring written as text here. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, the value of "This is the result now:" is put in a cell, and you want to remove `,` before "NPA". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct, Mr. @Tanaike!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, about `,` before the value of `NPA`, the value is always `NPA`? And, what is the character between `MOTORCYCLE*` and `,NPA-SacramentoCA`? The blank space? Or, the line break? Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect as the text data?

Comment: Not really. The comma will come from the second iteration on, as that will be the another element of pushed into the array. So, I break the line with ```\n```, but the second line and the third and so will come with comma, as I am writing the array to the message, @Tanaike.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Not really. The comma will come from the second iteration on, as that will be the another element of pushed into the array. So, I break the line with \n, but the second line and the third and so will come with comma, as I am writing the array to the message.`.

Comment: @Tanaike. Sorry if I'm not clear. I'm looping over the rows and pushing the cell's value into the array. Then, I write the array as a text, but the text's lines cannot begin with a comma. I even though if there would be a conditional slice method of something like that to delete first character if it's a comma...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove first character from a string if it is a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182596/remove-first-character-from-a-string-if-it-is-a-comma)

Comment: Yes. As I had mentioned above, I didn't formulate the question correctly. Got it solved by appending the value to a string, instead of using an array to concatenate the cells' values, @Kos! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. There's probably cleaner ways of doing it, but it collects the value, then tests for a comma, then pushes to an array without the comma if one existed.

```
for (var a = 0; a < dataRng.length; a++) {
    if (dataRng[a][1] == true && dataRng[a][0] == 'SHIPPED' && dataRng[a][40] != 'Yes') {
      var aValue = dataRng[a][37].toString().replace(',', '') + '\n';
      if (aValue.charAt(0)=== ","){
        aValue = aValue.slice(1);
      }
      
      msgBody.push(aValue);
      
      var iteratedRow = a + 3
      sheet.getRange(iteratedRow, 41).setValue('Yes')      
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hi! For some reason, the comma is still there and I don't see any errors logged. Any idea as to why? Thanks!

Comment: The comma is not coming from the cell value, but when I write the msgBody with the array data... How would I go about deleting this comma coming from the array?

Comment: You answer is correct, but me, with my stupidity, couldn't make the correct question. Here's what I used instead of ```msgBody.push(aValue)```, I declared ```msgBody``` as an empty string and ```msgBody += aValue```. Thanks a lot for jumping in!

Comment: Thanks for accepting even though it didn't solve your particular issue.